# Crawler - como acessar varias paginas

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

Montei um código no node para buscar a versão do sistema e o nome do município de um portal, porem eu não estou conseguindo fazer ele buscar as informações de outro município apenas de um.

No request eu gostaria que ele entrasse em loop e acessasse outros endereços como esse http://transparencia.bocaiuvadosul.pr.gov.br:9191/pronimtb/index.asp e depois jogar informações no arquivo txt.

o codigo é esse:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://transparencia.matinhos.pr.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp', function(err,res,body) 

{
    if(err) console.log ('Err: ' + err);

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $ ('.Class_Relatorio').each(function(){

    var nmcliente = $(this).find('.Class_Relatorio tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2)').text().trim();
    var versao = $(this).find('.Class_Relatorio tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1)').text().trim();

    console.log('Titulo: ' + versao);

    fs.appendFile('versao.txt', nmcliente + '|' + versao + '|'+  '\n');

    })
})
```

Comment: Sorack eu posso colocar manualmente no codigo ou colocar todos os outros endereços dentro de um txt.]

Comment: A versão do node é a v8.12.0.

Comment: Tudo bem @Sorack é que eu nunca fiz nada ai to brincando ai isso já me ajudaria no meu trabalho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reescrevendo seu código para utilizar promessas e comportar uma lista de `URLs` ficaria algo assim:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { get } = require('request');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

// Transforma o "get" em uma função que retorna uma promessa
const promisedGET = promisify(get);

const visitar = async uri => {
  const { statusCode, body } = await promisedGET({ uri, encoding: 'binary' });

  // Retorna um erro caso o status seja diferente de 200
  if (statusCode !== 200) throw new Error(body);

  return { body };
}

const ler = async ({ body }) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);

  const cliente = $('table.Class_Relatorio tr:nth-of-type(4) > td:nth-of-type(2)').text().trim();
  const versao = $('table.Class_Relatorio tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1)').text().trim();

  return { cliente, versao };
}

const executar = async urls => {
  // Faz requisições para todos os sites da lista
  const paginas = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => visitar(url)));
  // Lê as páginas retornadas e transforma em objetos
  const linhas = await Promise.all(paginas.map(conteudo => ler(conteudo)));
  // Transforma as linhas em uma string de conteúdo
  const conteudo = linhas.map(({ cliente, versao }) => `${cliente} | ${versao} |`).join('\n');
  // grava o conteúdo no arquivo
  writeFileSync('versao.txt', conteudo);

  return conteudo;
}

// Exemplo da chamada da função principal
(async () => {
  // Inicia o timer
  console.time('Execução');

  try {
    await executar([
      'http://transparencia.bocaiuvadosul.pr.gov.br:9191/pronimtb/index.asp',
      'http://transparencia.matinhos.pr.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp',
      'http://transparencia.rolandia.pr.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp',
      'http://transparencia.castanhal.pa.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp',
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  // Totaliza o tempo de execução
  console.timeEnd('Execução');
})();
```

Note que caso as informações não estejam disponíveis no local previsto (como é o caso de Rolândia) o resultado da linha não será o esperado. Sendo assim a saída da execução acima no arquivo `versão.txt` é:

> ```
> Prefeitura Municipal de Bocaiúva do Sul | PRONIM TB 518.01.07-013 |
> Prefeitura Municipal de Matinhos | PRONIM TB 518.01.04-000 |
>  | PRONIM TB 518.01.07-012 |
> Prefeitura Municipal de Castanhal | PRONIM TB 518.01.07-012 |
> ```

Comment: Maravilha. Era esse o resultado que eu buscava. Obrigado